# Exposing docker to the world

Tags: docker

I've setup an Ubuntu server with docker-ce. Here I'm running a small docker container, which works fine. It starts up a tomcat image, exposing 8080 to local port 80. I've tested `docker exec -it` to it, and it works.

But when I throw up my browser and try to reach it through my ubuntu host ip address, I get nothing. If I open a terminal and SSH to my ubuntu server and try to `curl localhost`, I get a Connection refused error.

I checked my iptables, and there is a chain for DOCKER present with a source of 0.0.0.0/0 and the exposed tcp dpt:80 port.

Googling around, I see people referencing `docker-machine`. This is not installed, so I installed it. This wants me to create something, so I try to create a docker-machine. But this requires virtualbox, so I install that. Virtualbox won't start until I modify my BIOS.... **is this all nescessary?**

I would think that just installing docker-ce would be enough. It's enough on my local windows box, why can't it be enough on my cloud hosted ubuntu server? What am I missing?

**Dockerfile**

```
#####################
## Stage 1: Build  ##

# We base this builder on tomcat, as our build script relies heavily
# on tomcat libraries
FROM tomcat:7.0-jre7 as builder

# Install sources
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | bash && \
    curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

# We install our build environment (java 1.7, ant and node)
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jdk ant apt-transport-https nodejs yarn git

# We set the java options needed to compile this
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING=false -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"

# Then we copy in our app and libraries used for building it
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
COPY tomcat/lib /usr/local/tomcat/lib

# Run frontend dependency installation (npm and bower)
RUN echo '{ "allow_root": true }' > /root/.bowerrc && yarn install

# We build it (this will also deploy it to this tomcat container
# but the tomcat container will never startup before the build stage
# is discarded)
RUN ant clean init jar-dev-configuration compile deploy


#####################
## Stage 2: Runner ##
FROM tomcat:7.0-jre7-alpine

# Copy in local configuration
COPY tomcat/conf /usr/local/tomcat/conf
COPY tomcat/lib /usr/local/tomcat/lib

# Copy in built products
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/kx /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/kx
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/portal /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/portal

EXPOSE 8080
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      # Upload folders should be local 
      - ./upload:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/portal/upload:rw
```

Comment: `docker-machine` is an old way to do stuff (back when windows and macs didn't have native docker support, a linux vm was used).
An ubuntu older than 14 should deal with it just fine.
Are you sure the container is bound not to localhost inside the container?

Comment: Then why can't I even curl and get a response? I'm running Ubuntu 16LTS...

Comment: If the process inside the container binds to a loopback ip (127.0.0.1) then any traffic from outside the container will never reach it. Try binding the service to 0.0.0.0

Comment: Isn't that what the IpTables chain i for? It's mentioned in the post above

Comment: The chain rule will forward traffic from any interface on the "host" to the ip of the container, not the lo interface of the container.

Comment: Not speaking much linux here. Could you please elaborate? How can I find out if there is such a loopback present? And how can I bind the docker service to 0.0.0.0?

Comment: Pasting your docker-compose file or docker run command should be quite helpful for a start, just to have a better overview.
The service inside the container needs to bind to 0.0.0.0, thats up to the service. Lots of applications bind to 127.0.0.1 by default.

Comment: Updated issue to include Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml.

Comment: Looks like tomcat:7.0-jre7 is doing the correct bind: `tcp        0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN` so this is not the case of loopback. Ports look reversed though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From given information, I can tell, that in your `docker-compose.yml` you are exposing port `8080` onto your host machine (thus, to the world) and port `80` into your container.

Try swapping them to:

```
ports:
# host:container
 - 80:8080
```